# What does this code mean " !pip install xlrd " in matplotlib ? Specially this "!" sign?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip, jupyter

I do not understand what is doing this "!" sign in Jupyter notebook to install xlrd. 
To install some library, I know that I need to write in the cmd "pip install . But here what is doing this "!" sigh in Jupyter notebook to install ... 
Thanks

Comment: those with ! sign jupiter executes like console command. Try this with !ls, etc... This will install module xldr for python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute a shell command inside jupyter notebook, you start with `!`. `pip install xlrd` is a shell command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, once I have installed the package in Jupyter, it is also installed in my local PC, so that I can access this particular package using Spyder or PyCharm too....????

Comment: @RakiOpu Right.